# Cloud9 and mongodb show data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I have created chat application using node.js , socket.io and **mongodb** on Cloud9.

I have created schema and model using this code :

```
    //mongoose connect
mongoose.connect('mongodb://test-mmnnww123.c9users.io:27017/chat', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('CONNECTED!');
    }
});

//mongoose model
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nick : String,
    msg : String,
    created : {type : Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);
```

Everything works perfectly and I  store the data successfully but I couldn't view the data, in other words i want to show that table that I have created which is called **Message**.

Is there URL for it or any npm command should I write to view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can connect to the mongodb server like that. Since cloud9 only exports ports `8080`, `8081`, and `8082` you won't be able to access `27017` externally.

To access the local mongodb server, you should be able to use `mongodb://localhost:27017` instead and that should work.